# Wrapping all ADUsers in a CSV File

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I want to retrieve, in a CSV file, all AD users. But every time I run my script the CSV file has a different amount of users.

I know there are up to 4000 users... but retrieved sometimes 500 to 600 results.

I noticed in my CSV file, at the last row something like

```
"Person Name", "person.name@email.com","person.name","CN=somewhere,OU=USERS,OU=THERE,OU=HERE,OU=SOMEPLACE,OU=ORG,DC= (here is the part where it breaks)
```

I noticed, always in the final row, the result is break. Is there a limit to my CSV file?

I can't figure out, what is happenning.

```
$path = ".\Users.csv"

$root = [adsi]''
$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root)
$searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))"
$searcher.PageSize = 5000 #iknow the max is 1000, but when i do it, and count my result, its show up 4000+
$searcher.SizeLimit = 5000


$cols = "cn", "mail", "samaccountname", "distinguishedname"
foreach ($i in $cols) {$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

$users = $searcher.FindAll() |
  Select-Object @{e={$_.properties.cn};n='DisplayName'},
                @{e={$_.properties.mail};n='Email'},
                @{e={$_.properties.samaccountname};n='sAMAccountName'},
                @{e={$_.properties.distinguishedname};n='distinguishedname'}

$users | Export-Csv $path -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default #now delimiting using ";" to do have problems with my string with commas
```

Comment: If I count this variable $users, its show me 4192.

Comment: Are you unable to use the Active Directory cmdlets?

Comment: No. I started to use this methods because, I wasnt enable to retrieve all users in every OU... and the the Client AD is.a.mass.

Comment: In a PowerShell console, run `Get-ADUser -Filter *` and see what gets spat out, pay special attention to the last item. It's possible there is bad data in your directory which is causing these tools break when they get there? Also try `Get-AdUser -Filter * | Measure-Object` so get a count of what that cmdlet is returning.

Comment: Also, do you have multiple domains/forests/trees? It's possible you're only searching one if that is the case.

Comment: [Maybe related](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180880%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I set this properties both to 1000. But, my result in the last row is break. Thanks, i did not know abou SizeLimit!

Comment: @Windos, Only one domain :0

Comment: @BenjaminHubbard - you mentioned using AD cmdlets. This is a question I have struggled with for some time now. Is there an advantage/disadvantage to using AD cmdlets vs System.DirectoryServices? I am trying to figure out what is best practice and most efficient for clients of mine. Thanks!

Comment: I put my answer in your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862471/should-i-use-the-active-directory-module-cmdlets-or-directoryservices-net-class/33882218#33882218

Answer (score 3):

Use the ActiveDirectory module cmdlets. So much easier. Looks something like this:

```
$path = ".\Users.csv"
Get-ADUser -Filter * | 
  Select-Object cn, mail, samaccountname, distinguishedname |
  Export-Csv -Path $Path
```

Depending on your version of PowerShell, you may need to manually import the module.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

Comment: In this command you don't use where to start the search? Like "root", "base" or "subtree" ? That was my first approach... I will try and try!

Comment: I tried this command, its the same problem. The last record is break... its the same thing I done, if we select samAccountName only... we get more records. If we do Select-Object *, I get less results... and the last record is break. Do you know any property that says "I WANT MOAR RESULTS IN THAT FILE"?

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue you're having, @BrunoGomes, but just for your first comment on this answer, you can target a specific OU with the `-SearchBase` parameter, e.g. `Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=staff,OU=users,DC=example,DC=com' | ...`

Comment: And if you don't specify a search base it'll just search everywhere.

Comment: I was thinking, if I can searcch by each OU, create a lot of csv, and them put everything togetter. :)

Comment: I frequently pull thousands of records using Get-ADUser, so it's not a limitation on the cmdlet. You must have some bad data, like Windos suggested.

Comment: @BenjaminHubbard, can you explain Bad Data? Because, mabe the problem is the "distinguishedname", this field is kind big...

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion if you want to massively export data from an AD you can use integrated tools like `LDIFDE.EXE` to use `LDIF` format, if you want to export to `CSV` format you can use `CSVDE.EXE`.

```
csvde -f exportfile.csv -d "DC=SILOGIX-ESS01,DC=local" -r "(&
(objectClass=user))" -l DisplayName,Email,sAMAccountName,distinguishedname
```

[CSVDE.EXE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732101.aspx) is a native Microsoft tool.

Comment: A tested this command. And i got the same problem, not all records come and the last record is break. But is a good way to retrieve itens.
I think, the problem is how my file is. Its comma separeted, And the domain distinguishedname, is a string with a lot of commas. Maybe i export as a separete by ";".... lets see

Comment: In my mind, CSVDE and LDIFDE were able to come accross the 1024 records limit.

Comment: If you, use this command to show ALL fields, will it print evreything?

Comment: As far as I know the answer is Yes.